# Find Duplicate Rows in SQL Server and Include All Rows

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I need a query that will return duplicated rows in a SQL Server table based on a set of column comparisons within the table.  I've gotten close with this:

```
DECLARE @startDate AS DATETIME = '9/1/2017';
DECLARE @endDate AS DATETIME = '9/2/2017';

WITH DupRecordSet AS
(
    SELECT 
        *, 
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY CCACaseId, Decision, DecisionDate, Extension, [Filename], Medicaid, MMISBillingNumber, NarrativeOfComments, NPIProviderId, OACNarrative, OHAdministrativeCode, PostSubmissionStateDate, PreSubmissionStateDate, ProviderID, ProviderRequestNarrative, RequestDate, ServiceTypeAuthRequest, Source, StateHearingDate, TypeOfRequest, UMTDPostSubmissionStateId, UMTDPreSubmissionRejectReasonId, UMTDPreSubmissionStateId ORDER BY (SELECT 0)) AS DuplicateRowNumber
    FROM 
        CTSMember01.dbo.UMTDRecord
    WHERE 
        DecisionDate BETWEEN @startDate AND @endDate
), DisplayRecordSet AS 
(
    SELECT 
        *
    FROM 
        DupRecordSet
    WHERE 
        DupRecordSet.DuplicateRowNumber > 1
)
SELECT *
FROM DisplayRecordSet;
```

but the problem is that this only includes the "extra" rows. In other words, in a case where 3 duplicate rows are found, this query will return the second and third rows, but not the first. I need all three rows.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `COUNT(*) OVER(...)` instead of `ROW_NUMBER`:

```
DECLARE @startDate AS DATETIME = '9/1/2017';
DECLARE @endDate AS DATETIME = '9/2/2017';

WITH
    DupRecordSet
    AS
    (
        SELECT *, COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY CCACaseId, Decision, DecisionDate, Extension, [Filename], Medicaid, MMISBillingNumber, NarrativeOfComments, NPIProviderId, OACNarrative, OHAdministrativeCode, PostSubmissionStateDate, PreSubmissionStateDate, ProviderID, ProviderRequestNarrative, RequestDate, ServiceTypeAuthRequest, Source, StateHearingDate, TypeOfRequest, UMTDPostSubmissionStateId, UMTDPreSubmissionRejectReasonId, UMTDPreSubmissionStateId) AS DuplicateRowNumber
        FROM CTSMember01.dbo.UMTDRecord
        WHERE DecisionDate BETWEEN @startDate AND @endDate
    ),
    DisplayRecordSet
    AS
    (
        SELECT *
        FROM DupRecordSet
        WHERE DupRecordSet.DuplicateRowNumber > 1
    )
SELECT *
FROM DisplayRecordSet;
```

Comment: Beautiful!  Thanks!